# Is there a way to use outlook mail groups as a Sharepoint group?

Tags: permissions, groups, people-picker, outlook

How can i use a outlook mail group  as a sharepoint group. Because i want to use these groups for permissions.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint groups and domain groups are different, also you can use outlook e-mail groups for granting permissions. If you want to see outlook groups at people picker, you need to define outlook group as "Security Group"

[Here](http://www.sharepointpitstop.com/2014/09/ad-groups-not-displayed-in-sharepoint.html) is more info

Comment: Thank you so much. But i want to ask something , what is the difference between sharepoint groups distribution groups and securtiy groups? I am afraid to generate security bug. Is a security group an admin ? What is the security groups authority , limitations, constraints?

Comment: AD groups and SharePoint groups have pros and cons. You can check these pros and cons from here.

http://sharepointmaven.com/active-directory-groups-sharepoint-groups/
Also this is the best explanation of difference between distribution and security groups.

"The only difference is that you cannot assign permissions to distribution groups. They are using for mail distribution only."

Here is more info about that.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3e8a510-67d5-4571-94eb-b85cb95e9371/difference-between-distribution-group-and-security-group?forum=winserversecurity